# Multiple bundles with Aurelia + Webpack 2

Tags: webpack, bundler, aurelia

## Background

I'm trying to create a project using [Aurelia](http://aurelia.io/), using [Webpack2](https://webpack.js.org/) for bundling. The code is written using [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/). I use [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/) to handle the [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/) dependencies.

My webpage is going to consist of multiple core HTML pages. The idea is then to have one Aurelia App for each of these pages.

So the `index.html` on each of these pages would have a `<div aurelia-app="some_module">`, each referring to a different module. Each of these are then located in their own bundle. Shared code between them are in separate bundles.

## Current config

My directory structure looks as follows:

```
aurelia-webpack/src/monitor/    # main.ts, app.ts, app.html
aurelia-webpack/src/test/       # main.ts, app.ts, app.html
```

So to start with I have this Webpack config. My `index.html` looks like this (The `{% static` stuff is from Django):

```
<div aurelia-app="main">
    <p>Loading...</p>
    <script src="{% static "aurelia-webpack/dist/app.js" %}"></script>
</div>
```

Then I have this config.

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path');
const { AureliaPlugin } = require('aurelia-webpack-plugin');
const { optimize: { CommonsChunkPlugin }, ProvidePlugin } = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: ['aurelia-bootstrapper'],
        vendor: ['bluebird', 'jquery', 'bootstrap'],
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].js",
        chunkFilename: "[name].js",
        sourceMapFilename: "[name].js.map",
        publicPath: "/dist/",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".js"],
        modules: [
            "src/monitor",
            "node_modules"
        ].map(x => path.resolve(x))
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.css$/i, use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"] },
            { test: /\.ts$/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader" },
            { test: /\.html$/, loader: "html-loader" }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new AureliaPlugin(),
        new ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery"
    })
    ]
}
```

## Result

This works fine with a hello world app for `monitor`. When I build using Webpack I can see this:

```
...
[app] ./src/monitor/app.ts 156 bytes {0} [built]
[app.html] ./src/monitor/app.html 57 bytes {0} [built]
[main] ./src/monitor/main.ts 267 bytes {0} [built]
...
```

And I can load the page fine and it renders as expected.

As you can see I use `aurelia-webpack-plugin` as well as `aurelia-bootstrapper`. If I have understood it correctly, the bootstrapper is the one responsible to find the `aurelia-app` tag on my `<div>` and injecting the `aurelia` bits there, based on the module name `main` that I refer to.

The contents of my `main.ts`:

```
import { Aurelia, PLATFORM } from 'aurelia-framework';

export function configure(aurelia: Aurelia)
{
aurelia.use
        .standardConfiguration()
        .developmentLogging();
aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName('app')));
}
```

## Confusion

However, these two are doing some "magic" things that I have a hard time following.

For example I don't understand how the `module` name is decided. In this case it's `main`, but I never configure that explicitly. That is somehow done by `aurelia-bootstrapper` or the `aurelia-webpack-plugin`?

When reading the WebPack manual on the entry it is a lot clearer:
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/#entry

> Simple rule: one entry point per HTML page. SPA: one entry point, MPA: multiple entry points.

```
entry: {
home: "./home.js",
about: "./about.js",
contact: "./contact.js"
}
```

## What I want

With all of the above, what I now want is to be able to add more entry points/modules/apps or whatever the correct term is.

I want to be able to create 2 or more index files:

**Monitor**:

```
<div aurelia-app="monitor">
    <p>Loading...</p>
    <script src="{% static "aurelia-webpack/dist/monitor.js" %}"></script>
</div>
```

**Test**:

```
<div aurelia-app="test">
    <p>Loading...</p>
    <script src="{% static "aurelia-webpack/dist/test.js" %}"></script>
</div>
```

each of these having their own bundle/entry point/module/app, how do I configure this with **Webpack** and **Aurelia**?

Is the use case for the **aurelia-webpack-plugin** somehow limited to only one entry point? I've tried adding explicit entries for `src/monitor/main.ts` and `src/test/main.ts` but I don't get anything to work properly.

Comment: Did you ever get this going?

Comment: Yes, read the answer I posted

Answer (score 1):

I found this issue on the **aurelia-webpack** github project that explains that this is by design:
https://github.com/jods4/aurelia-webpack-build/issues/35#issuecomment-302657535

The summary is that one has to use multiple compilations for each entrypoint. Since the config of webpack is **JavaScript**, these configs can share most of the settings for a base config and then simply import those for each entry point.

See the issue thread for more details and context.

The author clarified on this in the above mentioned thread:

> You are correct, the plugin API is designed for single entry point
>   (SPA) first. With steps from that other comment, I see no reason why
>   multiple entry points would not work, but it's hard to figure that out
>   on your own without a deep understanding of how Aurelia+Webpack+the
>   plugin work together. If this is common enough, maybe I should think
>   about adding simpler support for multiple entry points. (There's no
>   plan right now, but why not?)

Comment: I have been doing exactly the same for a project based on ASPNET core.  I created a common webpack bundle for vendor assets and then a bundle for each of my pages which are effectively independent Aurelia apps. I then  reference them the same as you have, i.e. in the page which bootstraps the Aurelia app. This means I have a webpack config for each of my apps, e.g. webpack.config.monitor.js & webpack.config.test.js.  Is this what you are doing too? J

Comment: Yes exactly like that

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up on my comment below. Here are some screenshots of the relevant section in each of my webpack configs.

**My Dashboard Page - dashboard.js created by webpack.config.dashboard.js**

[image: weback.config.dashboard.js]

**My Account Page - account.js created by webpack.config.account.js**

[image: weback.config.account.js]

This does work in my own aspnet core app so I see no reason why it would not for any other framework. You can also keep each "app" specific js file light by creating the vendor.js file and using the Webpack DLL plugin to create a manifest file which the app page scripts can reference.

However, whilst this works I am not sure it is the best way to achieve the results. Since each "page" is a completely independent Aurelia app I can only share state by using some other browser means, e.g. session or local storage. I may look at Aurelia "Features" as a way to split up the apps features - kind of makes sense.